# how I can set ID in Django REST Framework JSON:API response?

Tags: python, django, json-api

I am using Django REST Framework JSON:API.
Then, I want to set ID in the response.

I know the response gets ID from Django model instance.
But, if I set the instance to the serializer, the ID will be null.

## Example

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

```
class TagDetailView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = TagSerializer(data={"name": tag.name, "memo": "memo"})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=200)
```

## Expected

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "TagDetailView",
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "name": "name",
            "memo": "memo"
        }
    }
}
```

## As-Is

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "TagDetailView",
        "id": null, //  I WANT TO SET THE ID HERE
        "attributes": {
            "name": "name",
            "memo": "memo"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're passing initial data of serializer to your Response. In fact, you don't use your TagSerializer to serialize data from model instance to json.

Secondly, you have `Tag` model, so try to use `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.Serializer`.

To solve your problem, I'd do following:

1. Change your serializer

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    memo = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name="get_memo")  # if you want to add some custom field which is not in your model

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = "__all__"
   
    def get_memo(self, obj: Tag) -> str:
        return "memo"
```

2. Change a bit your APIView

```
from typing import Optional


class TagDetailView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        tag: Optional[Tag] = Tag.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
        if tag is None:
            return Response(data={}, status=404)
        data = TagSerializer(tag).data # passing instance of Tag to serializer
        return Response(data=data, status=200)
```

So, now you should have "id" in your response as far as we provided `fields = "__all__"` for `TagSerializer`